# Is it possible to disable the automatic smart card minidriver installation for a specific smart card hardware ID in Windows?

Tags: .net, windows, smartcard

I have a .NET application that uses WinSCard directly to communicate to a proprietary application on a smart card.

When a card is first inserted, Windows notifies the user it is searching for drivers and fails, which I would like to avoid.

I would rather not author a minidriver for my smart card because I have already written a managed library that performs all of the heavy lifting through WinSCard.  Is there a way to tell Windows not to install a driver for that particular device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know enough about it to tell you exactly what to do, but you need to install an INF file that *doesn't* have an associated driver (i.e. you're saying, "I'm taking care of this device")

Comment: After some googling, this is often called "null driver"

Answer (score 1):

Try this to disable smart card Plug and Play in local Group Policy

1. On a client computer, click *Start*, type `gpedit.msc` in the Search programs and files box, and then press Enter.
2. In the console tree under *Computer Configuration*, click *Administrative Templates*.
3. In the details pane, double-click *Windows Components*, and then double-click *Smart Card*.
4. Right-click *Turn on Smart Card Plug and Play service*, and then click Edit.
5. Click *Disabled*, and then click OK.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979547(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

[@Paul-Betts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5728/paul-betts) is [absolutely right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6839308/692942) and I spent some time trying to workout how to install a SmartCard Mini Driver for MIFARE DESFire cards as I was using PCSC directly and a card driver just wasn't required.

In the end I found a useful article that provided a Utility that would allow you to register specific cards against the null mini driver.

- [WINDOWS 7 COMPLAINS ON MISSING DRIVER FOR SMARTCARDS – A PRACTICAL WORKAROUND](http://tech.springcard.com/2011/windows-7-smartcard-driver-missing-workaround/)

The provided files come with the source and two batch files

- `pcsc_no_minidriver_memory.cmd` disables every memory card *(ATR constructed according to PC/SC v.2 specification for memory cards)*
- `pcsc_no_minidriver_well_known.cmd` disables  some well-known contactless cards that do not have a minidriver *(NXP Desfire, NXP Mifare Plus, various Calypso cards, …)*

It does come with a warning though;

> *Of course, **use this software and the related scripts with care and make sure you really do understand what it does**, as it may prevent your system to work correctly with your 20$-cryptographic card that do need its minidriver to work with CryptoAPI.*